# set and its translation are still disjoint

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

$\mathbb Q(A)$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb R$ containing $A.$

$\textbf{Theorem}$. Let $A,B\subset\mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb Q(A)\cap B=\emptyset$. If for each $r\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ let $D_{r}=r\cdot B.$ then $D_{r}\cap C=\emptyset$ where $C\subset\mathbb A.$

$\textbf{Proof}$. BWOC, assume $D_{r}\cap C\neq\emptyset$  then there exits $x\in D_{r}\cap C$. Then, there exist $r\in\mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \}$, $b\in B$, and $c\in C$ such that $x=r\cdot b$ and $x=c.$

$$ r\cdot b=c\in \mathbb Q(C).$$
$$b=r^{-1}\ c\in \mathbb Q(C)\subset\mathbb Q(A).$$
which is a contradiction since $\mathbb Q(A)\cap B=\emptyset.$
Could you please check if  there is something wrong in my argument ?

Comment: @Beric could you explain more please

Comment: The statement of the theorem is a bit unclear. Why $r^{-1}c\in\mathbb Q(C)$? I agree if $r$ is rational, or in $\mathbb Q(C)$, but it is not necessarily so.

Comment: @SMM, since they are equal i just multiple both side by $r$ since $r\neq 0$

Comment: Yes, $b=r^{-1}c$, but why does this belong to $\mathbb Q(C)$?